# Resetting the value of a property to the default or setting it to initial for better performance

Tags: html, css

For example, in CSS the default value of many properties is `none`, if I had previously changed its value to something else and later in the code I wanted to change it back to default, does it make any difference in performance efficient to set it to `initial` or explicitly change it to `none`?

e.g.:

```
div{
    float: right;
}
div:nth-child(odd){
    float: none;
}
```

or

```
div{
    float: right;
}
div:nth-child(odd){
    float: initial;
}
```

And if it does make a difference, is it really important to care about it or with nowadays computers the loading difference is so small that it is really not worth caring about?

Comment: The initial value is probably `none`

Comment: yes I know, what I meant with my question is if saying none is more efficient than saying initial since I am assuming that when I set the value to initial the browser needs to look up what is the initial value to then set it to none

Comment: Actually browser has already read all the css lines in sequential manner, it has stacked all properties in its cache so its no big deal for it to load the previous (initial properties). so dont worry

Comment: its better to use property initial because setting it again to none might give you some trouble when you need to make any change in you style-sheet in future and you would have to change everywhere where needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that using the default property (`none` for example) is probably faster than using `initial`, because `initial` still needs to be computed. But any way, the difference is really really negligible that you should not care about, otherwise you will be doing micro-optimization :

> The First Rule of Program Optimisation: **Don't do it.**
>
> The Second Rule of Program Optimisation (for experts only!): **Don't do it yet.**

*Quote from [Michael A. Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson)*

Another think to consider, is that `initial` is not supported in IE11.
Also `initial` is sometimes confusing, for example : for a `div` the initial value of `display` is `inline`, while the browser's default is `block`. So the `initial` value is of limited usefulness.